# WPF application rendering random pixelation

Tags: wpf

When my application is running...the rendering randomly gets all sorts of pixelated and wierd colours appear. If I change focus to another application and get back it looks normal again. This happens randomly. What is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a problem of the graphics card to me. Do you have the latest drivers?
Did you try other WPF applications? Maybe a program not written my you?